# One/One.app is reloading continuously

Tags: lightning-aura-components

i just tried one/one.app from my chrome browser and it is keep on reloading, i am getting the below console message.

```
PORT_NAME_SYMANTEC_PKI_CLIENT_CONTENT_TO_BACKGROUND...
bridge.js:1 Connected: Port {}
bridge.js:1 Done.
detection.js:1 +content/detection.js
detection.js:1 -content/detection.js
app.js:118909 [Beacon.cmp] Enqueueing action to send using blocking xhr on window unload
app.js:118912 navigating away from page. uploading beacon
aura_proddebug.js:10868 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

I thought it is due to locker service , so i disabled locker service but again same issue.

Comment: Pretty sure problem is with chrome extension which is installed at your browser -- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/symantec-authentication-c/ahgdclgdhfeingghldkedleghekbfhef?hl=en

Comment: I dont have symantec extension in my chrome browser, it is happening for only one sandbox(winter 17).